# Display posts with tag for custom post type only

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I have this is my `functions.php` file to create tags only for custom post type called 'image-gallery':

```
register_taxonomy(
  'image-gallery_tags',
  'image-gallery',
  array(
    'label'        => __( 'Image Tags' ),
    'rewrite'      => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'capabilities' => array( 'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories' )
  )
);
```

But I can't get the list of tags to show in the post loop on the front end. I have tried `get_the_tags();` and  `get_the_tag_list();` but they will only show tags which are generic to all posts, not the tags for the custom post type. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_tags()` is a shortcut function to get the terms from the `post_tags` `taxonomy`.

What you have done is make a new and different `taxonomy`. And you will need to use `get_the_terms()` to get your required data.

E.g.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post, 'image-gallery_tags');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/